# Multiplicação de matrizes em Python

Tags: python, matriz

Olá, estou fazendo um algoritmo em python que faz o produto entre duas matrizes,
mas estou com problema na hora de exibir a matriz resultante

```
matriz = []
linha = []
linha2= []
matriz_result = []
result = 0
lista = []
nlin,ncol= map(int,input().split())
for i in range(0,nlin):
 valor = (input().split())
 valor = list(map(int,valor))
 linha.append(valor)
 matriz.append(linha)


matriz2 = []
nlin2,ncol2 = map(int,input().split())
for i in range(0,nlin2):
 valor = (input().split())
 valor = list(map(int,valor))
 linha2.append(valor)
 matriz2.append(linha2)

for i in range(nlin):
 if ncol!=nlin2:
     print("ERRO")
 for j in range(ncol):
      for h in range(0,1):
           for k in range(ncol):
                result += matriz[i][i][k]*matriz2[k][k][i]
                matriz_result.append(result)



print(matriz_result)
```

Tenho que colocar as entradas da matriz na mesma linha, aí por algum motivo um elemento da matriz é dado por três parâmetros.

Alguém me diz o que preciso mudar no código?

Comment: Você não havia colocado a tag [python] em sua questão. Sem ela, quase ninguém a encontraria.

Comment: @lucas, as matrizes têm 3 dimensões? (esperava 2); se imprimires o valor de `matriz` está a parecer algo como ` [[[0, 1], [1, 0]], [[0, 1], [1, 0]]]`

Answer (score -1):

Mano , quando você pedi para o usuário inserir a lista você coloca a linha na variável valor , depois transforma em lista e depois coloca dentro de outra lista , por isso fica uma matriz com 3 índices .

Coloca direto na variável linha .

```
for i in range(0,nlin):
 linha = (input().split())
 linha = list(map(int,linha))
 matriz.append(linha)
```

Mas a Matriz Resultante não está somente com os elementos , ela mostra todos os fatores de cada elemento .

E também não está calculando certo os fatores , o próximo fator sempre tá sendo a soma dos fatores anteriores .

Além de que o `for j in range(ncol):` deve ser com `ncol2` ficando `for j in range(ncol2):` pois no `for i in range(nlin):` é definido a quantidade de linhas da matriz resultante que será a mesma quantidade de linhas da matriz 1 e no `for j in range(ncol):` será definido a quantidade de colunas da matriz resultante que será a mesma quantidade de colunas da matriz 2 e não da 1 como está representado .

O `for k in range(ncol):` também poderia ser escrito com `nlin2` mas não com `nlin` nem com `ncol2` pois nesse for é definida a quantidade de fatores que somados vão resultar em cada elemento da matriz resultante e essa quantidade de fatores é o mesmo que o valor das colunas da matriz 1 e das linhas da matriz 2 .

Esse `for h in range(0,1):` também é desnecessário , pois da maneira como está iria rodar somente uma vez mas todo código vai rodar pelo menos uma vez .

Nesse site [Página no ScriptBrasil](https://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/185978-ajuda-como-multiplicar-matrizes/) mostra uma forma correta de multiplicar matrizes .